# Get the layer where feature are snapped PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, snapping

Is there a way to get the `QgsVectorLayer` on which the features of another layer have been snapped?

I need to connect the `featureAdded` signal of the starting layer to a method.

In the following image when adding a feature to the `point` layer and if it is snapped to another layer, e.g. the red line, is there a way to get the `QgsVectorLayer` object of the line?

Snapping is activated manually by the user and not with PyQGIS.

```
project = QgsProject.instance()

points = project.mapLayersByName('points')[0]


def my_method():
    pass

points.featureAdded.connect(my_method)
```

[image]